# Is there any response group larger than large in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

i want to know if there is larger than large retrieve data in aws response group?

i know only small, medium and large is there any larger than large?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the current "largest" instances on AWS

**Large by Memory**

High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large Instance

- 68.4 GB of memory
- 26 EC2 Compute Units (8 virtual cores with 3.25 EC2 Compute Units each)
- 1690 GB of instance storage
- 64-bit platform
- I/O Performance: High
- EBS-Optimized Available: 1000 Mbps
- API name: m2.4xlarge

**Large by CPU**

Cluster Compute Eight Extra Large Instance

- 60.5 GB of memory
- 88 EC2 Compute Units (2 x Intel Xeon E5-2670, eight-core "Sandy Bridge" architecture)
- 3370 GB of instance storage
- 64-bit platform
- I/O Performance: Very High (10 Gigabit Ethernet)
- EBS-Optimized Available: No*
- API name: cc2.8xlarge

**Large by IO**

High I/O Quadruple Extra Large Instance

- 60.5 GB of memory
- 35 EC2 Compute Units (16 virtual cores*)
- 2 SSD-based volumes each with 1024 GB of instance storage
- 64-bit platform
- I/O Performance: Very High (10 Gigabit Ethernet)
- Storage I/O Performance: Very High**
- EBS-Optimized Available: No***
- API name: hi1.4xlarge

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: so i will use "Cluster Compute Eight Extra Large"?

Comment: how can i use it response group?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the answer is No.

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Large.html, the Large Response Group does not have any Parent Response Groups.

> The Medium and Large response group are for demonstration purpose and is not
>   suitable for production applications. Precise required response groups
>   should always be used in applications to reduce latency and response
>   size.

Product Advertising API includes the following response groups:

- Accessories
- AlternateVersions
- BrowseNodeInfo
- BrowseNodes
- Cart
- CartNewReleases
- CartTopSellers
- CartSimilarities
- EditorialReview
- Images
- ItemAttributes
- ItemIds
- Large
- Medium
- MostGifted
- MostWishedFor
- NewReleases
- OfferFull
- OfferListings
- Offers
- OfferSummary
- PromotionSummary
- RelatedItems
- Request
- Reviews
- SalesRank
- SearchBins
- Similarities
- Small
- TopSellers
- Tracks
- Variations
- VariationImages
- VariationMatrix
- VariationOffers
- VariationSummary

See API Reference at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ApiReference.html for more information